# Want to save image and video in specific folder

Tags: android, android-studio, save, uri

I get my Image and video in Uri. I want to save that file in specific folder in internal memory. I tried Fileoutputstream and all but I can save it in camera folder but not specific folder. I want to save both image and video.

```
 public void onClick(View view) {

            if (string.contains("jpg")) {
                String path = null;
                try {

                    path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                            string, "img", null);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                final Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                saveImageandVideo(uri);


            } else {
                 Uri uri = Uri.parse(string);
                saveImage(uri);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        }

    });
```

my save code here

```
private void saveImageandVideo(Uri uri) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();


    File myDir = new File(root + "/folder_name");
    if (!myDir.exists()) {

        myDir.mkdirs();

    }


    try {

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);


        out.flush();

        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This code work but I can't able to save it in specific folder. It automatically saved it in camera folder(DCIM). and I can't able to save the videos. waiting for answers friends. Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

> Change your `file` variable creation as follows.

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();

File myDir = new File(root + "/folder_name");
if (!myDir.exists()) {
    myDir.mkdirs();
}
File file = new File(myDir,"filename.jpg/mp4");
//rest of your code
```

> Change your saveImageandVideo() as

```
private void saveImageandVideo() {
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);    
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: FileUtils not working and this code not working properly bro.... actual problem is it's not save in specific folder. Your code is awesome but it's not suite in my case

Comment: @IlyasFahrudeen check my latest edited code. If your image is saving and not in the specified folder use the above code

Comment: @IlyasFahrudeen currently you created your `file` variable in some other folder and you saving that `file`. So change the file creation as above - mentioned in comment

Comment: @IlyasFahrudeen change your file variable creation as mentioned above

Comment: let me check and tell you. Thank you bro :D

Comment: It's work bro. but proble is it save in default folder "DCIM". I mean camera folder.

Comment: Still in the save DCIM folder ? Please update your full code here. and make sure you use this `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();` not the previous one

Comment: @IlyasFahrudeen check weather there is a new folder created in your root directory

Comment: yes bro. new folder created and i test with dummy text. that text saved in that folder but when i try to save image or video. that save in DCIM folder. that's the problem

Comment: @IlyasFahrudeen in same place in your code you are changing the directly. Check in your download code and follow the file variable throughout the code and check any where you are changing the path

Comment: W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/content:/media/external/images/media/53143: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: This is what I get in Log